# Why am I not getting this bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674311/setting-up-environment-in-virtaulenv-using-python3-stuck-on-setuptools-pip-whe/45903517#45903517). I answered the question and got 3 upvotes on my answer after the bounty was set for the question but still, I didn't receive half of the bounty.

Comment: Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty You can read how bounty work.

Comment: @CodeLღver Now, Is I am eligible for yearling badge with 200 reputations.

Comment: Yes, After earning 200 reputation. You are eligible yearling batch. And you will get this every year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounty is still in the "grace period". After the bounty period ends, the OP still has 24 hours before the bounty is automatically assigned.